# Trouble posting more than once to webapi from Blazor component- "This instance has already started one or more requests."

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor (esp 6.0) and have a simple example which calls an API, after clicking a button, gets returned results, and displays in a component.  It works only the first time.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if I need to create a new instance of the HttpClient every time I make a request (which the BOL says not to do).
The error displayed after clicking the button a second time looks like so:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.
System.InvalidOperationException: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CheckDisposedOrStarted()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.set_BaseAddress(Uri value)
   at BlazorApp1.Pages.NumberGenerator.GetNumbersets(Root postData) in D:\Projects\TestNumbers\BlazorApp1\Pages\NumberGenerator.razor:line 74
   at BlazorApp1.Pages.NumberGenerator.ProcessForm() in D:\Projects\TestNumbers\BlazorApp1\Pages\NumberGenerator.razor:line 50
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

And here's the code:

```
@page "/numbergenerator"
@inject HttpClient client
@using System.Text.Json

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Number Set Generator</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="btnget" type="submit" @onclick="ProcessForm" class="btn btn-primary align-self-center">Generate Numbers</button>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="results">
        @if (Numbersets[0][0] != 0) //check to see if actual data
        {
            @foreach (int[] numberset in Numbersets)
            {
                NumberSetCount++;
                <div>
                    Set#@NumberSetCount.ToString() &nbsp;
                    @foreach (int number in numberset)
                    {
                        <span>@number.ToString()</span>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    }
                </div>
                <br />
            }
        }
    </div>

</div>

@code {

    public int[][]? Numbersets { get; set; }    // number sets returned as jagged array from api
    public int? NumberSetCount { get; set; }    // for display purposes

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //initialize everything
        NumberSetCount = 0;
        Numbersets = new int[][] { new int[] { 0 } }; //init with 1st array element (of parent array) to 0
    }

    private async Task ProcessForm()
    {
        //test data
        Models.Root postData = new() { sets = 10 };
        postData.numberGroups.Add(new Models.NumberGroup() { numbersPerGroup = 5, min = 1, max = 70, divergence = 15, oeCheck = true, sumCheck = true });
        postData.numberGroups.Add(new Models.NumberGroup() { numbersPerGroup = 1, min = 1, max = 25, divergence = 50, oeCheck = false, sumCheck = false });

        Numbersets = await GetNumbersets(postData);
    }

    private async Task<int[][]> GetNumbersets(Models.Root postData)
    {
        int[][] retval = new int[][] { new int[] { 0 } }; //init with 1st array element of main array to 0
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://api.**********.com/");
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(@"api/numbersets", postData);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string? responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (responseData != null)
                {
                    retval = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int[][]>(responseData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return retval;
    }


}
```

I suppose I need to somehow kill the last request, but not really sure how to go about it.

Again this is a Blazor Server App (DotNet 6).

**THE ANSWER:**

Moving the client.BaseAddress... to the OnInitialized() method did the trick.
The "properties" in the error message refers to those set in the HttpClient and can only be set once.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    //initialize everything
    NumberSetCount = 0;
    Numbersets = new int[][] { new int[] { 0 } }; //init with 1st array element (of parent array) to 0
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://api.********.com/");
}
```

Comment: Think you might be focusing on the wrong part of the error message. See *Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.*

Comment: So my next question is, does the API you're calling have a Swagger/OpenAPI spec ? When you browse to the API in a normal browser, do you see a website that looks like this: https://petstore.swagger.io/ / does it host some URL that produces a json document like this: https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

Comment: The return from the api looks like [[9,16,28,58,59,5],[1,12,25,42,68,15],[9,12,38,61,68,18],[20,21,34,49,64,2],[14,20,23,59,70,17],[22,31,34,53,68,17],[1,21,22,56,68,25],[1,32,38,39,68,14],[1,6,44,56,65,25],[9,26,40,42,53,1]]

Comment: Apparently, the property in question was  where I set the base address client.BaseAddress

Comment: I put it in the OnIntialized and there's no error now

Comment: Indeed. And now the answer to my second comment?

Comment: It does not describe itself. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out why DotNet 6 got rid of OnAfterRender()  - can't override a non-existent method, lol!

Comment: Do strive to use async where possible in blazor

Comment: *It does not describe itself* - if you have control of its code, you should install swagger/swashbuckle at the API end; it's fewer lines of code than you've written here to try and get a single operation working. Once installed you can use tooling like autorest or nswag to generate all this code you've written, and all your models. Change something at the server end, hit regenerate at the client end, problem solved. Your querying operations come down to 2 lines of code; make a client, call a method on it

Comment: If you don't have control of the API, NSwag studio will still have a do at generating you a client based on the json it can pull out, it's just a bit more manual work, which is why I'd say go for the OA spec approach first if its available/can be made available

Comment: Question was closed - but the other answers were for outdated versions of DotnetCore  and/or not Blazor related and a lot has changed in the last few years.